# variable undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude

i'm getting confusing about this problem. take a look at my code please.
when the function alert it says the lon and lat is not defined.
I watch the selectLat, selectLon, param in debuger, but the first two variable have the correct property though param.lat and param.lon are undefined.
what's wrong with them?

```
var selectLat,selectLon;

function showCurrent(s){

if(navigator.geolocation){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(s);
   }

}

function passLatLon(currentPos){
selectLat=currentPos.coords.latitude;
selectLon=currentPos.coords.longitude;

}
<script>
showCurrent(passLatLon);

var param={

lat:selectLat,
lon:selectLon,
};

function getResults(param, function(data){
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: you don't even call `getResults()` in this code example and have a lot of syntax errors. please provide an executable code example that reproduces the problem

Comment: but they not important. i missed closing script tag and. the fact that important is param.lat and param.lot is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
   function showCurrent(s){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(s);
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }      
    }

    function passLatLon(currentPos){
        var param = {
                selectLat:currentPos.coords.latitude,
                selectLon:currentPos.coords.longitude
            }
        getResults(param); //getResults() : You never called this
    }

    function getResults(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    showCurrent(passLatLon);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting: you are setting lat: selectLat before selectLat has been created.

Edit: Also notice: the comma at the end of lon:selectLon, generates a syntax error.

---

The main thing is: you're working with code that takes time to execute.  Before using the variables, you must wait until the service is ready.

---

This is probably what something like what you want.

```
<script>
var selectLat, selectLon, param;

// requests a position tracking
function showCurrent(successCallback) {
  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback);
  }
}

// callback.  This function gets triggered when the position was found
function passLatLon(currentPos) {
  selectLat=currentPos.coords.latitude;
  selectLon=currentPos.coords.longitude;
  // only now we can set var param
  param = {
    lat: selectLat,
    lon: selectLon
  };
  getResults(param);
}

// request position tracking
showCurrent(passLatLon);

function getResults(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}
</script>
```

EDIT: Pretty much the same thing as Rizo posted, about the same time

Answer (score 0):

When you defining this:

```
var param={

lat:selectLat,
lon:selectLon,
};
```

... `lat`→`selectLat`, `lon`→`selectLon` pairs ain't binded, you just assign current `selectLat`/`selectLon` values (which is undefined at the time of `param` declaration) to `lat`/`lon` properties.

You **do can** bind them (for example, via `Object.defineProperty`), but that's, probably, not what you want, really. Instead, try to get rid of `selectLat`/`selectLon` variables at all, like this:

```
var param = {
    lat: 0,
    lon: 0,
};

function passLatLon(currentPos){
    param.lat = currentPos.coords.latitude;
    param.lon = currentPos.coords.longitude;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Properties of `param` object never changes, as they aren't actually *binded* to `selectLat`/`selectLon` variables, so, whenever `selectLat`/`selectLon` variables changed, that doesn't affect `param` object.

You either must change `param` properties directly as @Rize and I suggested, or bind them to `selectLat`/`selectLon` via some workarounds and fire `change` event on yours model manually.

Yet another possible cause: `getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous, so right after the call `showCurrent(passLatLon)` coordinates are still unresolved and thus `selectLat`/`selectLon` are not set (`undefined` as they declared). Thats why after first call to `showCurrent()` they're `undefinded`, after second - they hold values to previous call and so on:

```
...

showCurrent(passLatLon); // first call, coordinates unresolved

var param={
lat:selectLat,
lon:selectLon,
};

function getResults(param, function(data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data)); // still unresolved
}

// somewhere around here geolocation service kicks in and passes
// coordinates to `passLatLon` function

// if you try to look at selectLat/selectLon at this point of executin,
// they will contain values from previous probe
```

Comment: first of all , the comma at the end of lon doesn't generate a syntax error.
second: I have a MVC model that i send request and then get response.
it works properly if i put it in onchange event. but here at the first of execution the server response me that the latitude and longitude are invalid though on the second execution the lat and lon has been set.
I think selectLat and selectLon aren't established at the first time though i put them global and on the top of function.

Comment: `the comma at the end of lon doesn't generate a syntax error` - and why it should? For second, read edit.